# MAC address of Hardware device(RFID) reader to finf unique identity Java code

Tags: java, mac-address

“ How can I get the MAC address of a Datagram sender at the receiver’s end ?

I have a UDP session established between two nodes and at the receiver side, I need to identify

The MAC ID of the sender. Is it possible ? Can I get this with the Socket descriptor itself ? “

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that:

```
A host cannot determine from the MAC address of another host whether that host is on the same link (network segment) as the sending host, or on a network segment bridged to that network segment.
```

`source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address#Usage_in_Hosts`